# Infinite loop when running pre-built facebook app by Heroku

Tags: facebook, heroku

If you register a facebook app and using Heroku's service, it will generate a sample app to you, since from few days ago, infinite loop occurs and you have no way to interact with your app. I tried to replace window.location = window.location; with window.top.location.href = "https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx":

```
//Listen to the auth.login which will be called when the user logs in
//using the Login button
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
// We want to reload the page now so PHP can read the cookie that the
// Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
// window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
// post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
// user asking if they want to send data again.
//window.location = window.location;
window.top.location.href = "https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APPs_NAMESPACE"
});
```

Luckily, it solved the problem. Just a sharing here.

Comment: In general You really [should post this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) in a Q & A format, that is state the question and then answer your own question in an answer (you can even do this when [posting the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question))

Comment: this didn't work for me.